# An Explicit Example of Galois Theory for Schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, schemes, etale-covers

I'm currently attempting to understand Galois theory for schemes, largely following the books *Galois Theory for Schemes* by Henrik Lenstra and *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups* by Tamas Szamuely. The main theorem is

> Let $X$ be a connected scheme. Then there exists a profinite group $\pi$, uniquely determined up to isomorphism, such that the category $\mathbf{FEt}_X$ of finite \'etale covers of $X$ is equivalent to the category $\pi$-$\mathbf{sets}$ of finite sets on which $\pi$ acts continuously.

I'm attempting to come up with some explicit examples of this equivalence/correspondence for specific schemes. If $X = \operatorname{Spec} k$ for some field $k$, then one simply recovers (Grothendieck's formulation of) Galois theory for fields. If $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{Z}$, then the finite \'etale covers just look like disjoint unions of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{Z}$, and the profinite group $\pi$ is trivial.

Both of these examples seem pretty boring though. Does anyone know of some interesting examples classifying the finite \'etale covers of some other scheme?

Comment: $\mathbb G_{m,k} \mapsto \hat{\mathbb Z}$ for any algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero? Slightly more interesting is that the same group works for a nodal cubic.

Comment: A famous example is the projective line minus three points; see Belyi's theorem.

Comment: For varieties over $\mathbb C$, you get the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group. This should give many interesting examples.

Comment: For a $k$-variety, there is an exact sequence $1 \to \pi_1(\bar{X}) \to \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(k) \to 1$. It follows that $\pi_1(\mathbf{P}^1_k) = \pi_1(k)$.

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~jacobt/Lecture7.pdf).